# Quick Sort VBA by Columns (Horizontally)

Tags: excel, vba, multidimensional-array, 2d, quicksort

I'm trying to sort by columns with a 2D array containing N Rows * 15 Columns.
I saw the quicksort algorithm but it only works for sorting Rows (Vertically).
What I need is sort by Columns. Does anybody help me to get that?
Here is my attempt

```
Public Arr As Variant
Public Sub QuickSortHorizontally()
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer

Dim LbdArr As Integer, UbdArr As Integer, Pvt As Integer
LbdArr = 1
UbdArr = 15

For i = LBound(Mtz, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
    For j = LBound(arr, 2) - 1 To UBound(arr, 2) - 1
        For k = LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2)                
            Pvt = arr(i, UBound(arr, 2))
            If arr(i, k) <= Pvt Then
                arr(i, k) = arr(k, i)
            End If
            Debug.Print arr(i, k) 'Just to see if it works
        Next k
    Next j
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you not use the 'Custom Sort' for columns?

Comment: Usually that option only works when there is only 1 row x N Columns.
My case I need to sort 15 Columns (Left to Right) of an array with N Rows. 
That excel feature doesn't work with this scenario.

Comment: I just tried that sort with 5 rows and 5 column and it worked for me. Maybe your data is more complex

Comment: If you have an algorithm that does QuickSort of a vertically oriented array, and your array is horizontally oriented, could you `WorksheetFunction.Transpose` the array, then sort vertically, then `WorksheetFunction.Transpose`f it back?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I really understand what you want, but try this:

```
Sub SortAllCols()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim cols, rows As Long

Set ws = ActiveSheet
cols = ws.UsedRange.Columns.Count
rows = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count

For i = 1 To rows
    ws.Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, cols)).Select
    ws.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ws.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, cols)), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ws.Sort
        .SetRange Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, cols))
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlLeftToRight
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: That is the idea. But instead ranges I need by general arrays. 
I will import the values from a TXT file or sometimes from a HTML table.
If I use your approch, that is very good by the way, I will have more steps putting all values in the spreadsheet then sorting afterwards.